# Is the composite state necessarily mixed when there are all but exactly one mixed state?

Tags: quantum-state

Let $\rho_A$ be a mixed state (density operator). If we wish, we can purify it and get a $\rho_{AB}$ that is pure on some composite Hilbert space $H_{AB}$. And by the question I just ask, [How to prove that tensor products of two pure density operators is again pure](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17762/how-to-prove-that-tensor-products-of-two-pure-density-operators-is-again-pure/17766#17766), we know that tensor product of pure states is again pure. Observing the results above, I just come up with a natural question: how about tensor product of all but exactly one mixed states? Is such composite state necessarily mixed? (I'm not a English speaker, which might have used a weird grammar; to be clear, I mean $\otimes_{i\in I} \rho_i$ is mixed whenever $\exists !~i\in I,~\rho_i$ is mixed) If we cannot make any conclusion, how about composite of *all but exactly one pure* state?

Answer (score 5):

A state is pure iff it is rank one and
$$
\mathrm{rank}\left(\bigotimes_i \rho_i \right) = \prod_i \mathrm{rank}(\rho_i). 
$$
This can be proven by considering the spectral decompositions of the $\rho_i$. So in answer to your question, your state is pure iff all of the $\rho_i$ are pure.

Answer (score 4):

The tensor product of a non-pure state with any other state gives a non-pure state.

One way to see it is noticing that the von Neumann entropy is additive with respect to tensor products: $S(\rho\otimes\sigma)=S(\rho)+S(\sigma)$ for any $\rho,\sigma$. Therefore if there is any $\rho_i$ that is not pure, then $S(\rho_i)>0$ and thus $S(\bigotimes_j\rho_j)>0$.

You can also just observe that a state being pure means that it is a rank-one projector, i.e. a projector with one-dimensional support. If any factor in a tensor product is not pure, then its support is at least two-dimensional, and thus so must be the support of the tensor product.